# ldapsearch for a list of users

Tags: bash, shell, posix, ldap-query

I want to expand my current ldapsearch query with an input file.
Here is the actual query I'm currently using for just one specific UID;

`ldapsearch -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 389 -b 'ou=My-OU,dc=MyDC' -w,somepwd -D'uid=someadmin,cn=Users,ou=My-OU,dc=MyDC' '(uid=someuid)' | awk '/STRING1*|STRING2*|STRING3*|STRING4*/'`

Instead of the last ldapsearch query field right before the pipe into the awk filter, I would like to input a file containing uid's separated by a new line and output the results into another file, which should look like this (every result separated by a newline);

1. UID1;ResultString1
2. UID1;ResultString3
3. UID2;ResultString1
4. UID2;ResultString2
5. UID3;ResultString1
6. UID3:ResultString4

Since I'm operating on a stripped down system, the preferred way to achieve this would be in POSIX-Shell or BASH.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The general approach: `< inputfiles awk ..... | xargs -d '\n' -i ldapsearch ..... -Duid={}.... | awk ..` should be enough to get you started.

Comment: instead of returning all attributes, you may only request the attributes that your are interested in ... that would be LDAP best practice. Return attributes are specified after the search filter.